# Trouble with masonry

Tags: wordpress, masonry

I wanted to use the masonry.js for the first time and I am getting trouble.... I checked for solutions but I don't/ can't see mistakes...

My Idea was to show the Posts in the Masonry of my WordPress feed. 
Would be really thankful for any help.
Thats the

```
<div id="masonry" class="article_div js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>>

    <?php query_posts('category_name=cat1, cat2, cat3');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="item">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

    <br class="clear">

</div>
```

The CSS file:

```
.article_div{
position:absolute;
top:100%;
background-color:#FFF;
min-height:100%;
width:100%;
padding-left:15%;
padding-right:15%;
}
.item{
width:45%;
}
```

Or do you have any other suggestions? 
Thank you for your help :*

Comment: If you have some kind of custom.js file where you can add your own jquery it's better to do it there. Plus you need to have necessary libraries enqueued in your wordpress theme (isotope.js, masonry.js etc.) for masonry to work.

Comment: i have masorny.js but i didnt post that part here

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, where ever you can add custom jquery code

```
var $isotope_container = $('#masonry');
var sortBy = 'random';
var columnWidth = '.item';

$isotope_container.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: columnWidth
    },
    itemSelector : '.item',
    sortBy: sortBy
});
```

You need to have [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) in your theme, and masonry as well.

Comment: i did the thingy you said now and still can't see any changes on the page it is still shown post below post. 

:/